# Transfer files from Ubuntu to a Windows 7 system on the same network

Tags: networking, 11.10

I don't know about Samba and stuff, and I don't care to share files on the network either. I just want to copy/move an ISO file form Ubuntu (the CD drive is not working) to a Windows 7 computer where I can safely burn it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you don't know Samba, it may be the easiest solution in this situation (or USB stick).

Just install samba, you'll also get GUI configuration tool:

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

Go to menu System -> Administration -> Samba

Click green plus, add share. Select the directory containing your ISO. Select visible, on the 2nd tab grant access to everyone. You can share with everyone if you are in the private network, you will cancel this share later.

After this, you should see Ubuntu machine from Windows and be able to access that directory. I hope this helps.

General help with samba: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba

Comment: There's no Administration in Unity (Oneiric). Searching for Samba turns up nothing. :( I'll see if I can get a USB.

Comment: Aah, unity. If you want, you can log to ubuntu classic. You can select it on the login screen: http://www.myconfinedspace.com/wp-content/uploads/tdomf/205276/ubuntu-classic.png

Comment: It's Oneiric. And Unity allows searching all the GNOME menu entries and filter them the same way as menus. The thing is there's nothing about Samba.

Comment: Well, the last try (in terminal) - this runs my samba config management: gksu system-config-samba

Comment: With `gksu`, the password entry area appeared, entered password, nothing happened. I remembered that I installed `system-config-samba` last time I messed with it, so ran `sudo system-config-samba` and the result was `sudo: system-config-samba: command not found`. I think I'll try installing it first.

Comment: Yes, I had to install it first, edit that into your answer, please. And I can see it on Unity as well. :)

Comment: I set up the share like you told me to - but how do I find it on Windows?